# How do you find the owner of a lock (Monitor)?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, monitor

Is there a way to discover what thread currently owns a lock?
Specifically I am looking for some code to print out the thread that is preventing a lock from being taken.  I want to try to lock for a given timeout, then report which thread is blocking the lock from being taken.

Comment: Why specific to C# ? Could be same doubt in case of java.

Comment: @Mask The problem probably exists in all/most runtimes/languages that has threading and locking, but he specifically asks for code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Just write the code:

```
private int lockOwner;
private object lockObject = new object();
...
void foo() {
    lock(lockObject) {
        lockOwner = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        // etc..
    }
}
```

There an otherwise undocumented way to get the lock owner, it isn't guaranteed to work but usually does.  When you have a breakpoint active use Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory1.  In the Address input box, type the name of the locking object ("lockObject") and press Enter.  The address box changes to the address of the object in memory.  Edit it and append "-4" to the address, press Enter.  The first 4 bytes in the dump gives you the ManagedThreadId in hexadecimal.  This works for 32-bit code, as long as you never called GetHashCode on the locking object.  Which of course you shouldn't.

Comment: You might want to fix the type of `lockObject`.

Comment: Could you explain about should not call GetHashCode() on an object used for locking?  Are you saying that in general or just for purposes of this memory peek?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED :**

**C# :**

- [Identify thread holding lock in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523544/identify-the-thread-which-holds-the-lock)

For C#, you can get your answer here :

From `Hans Passant`,

```
class Test {
    private object locker = new object();
    public void Run() {
        lock (locker) {  // <== breakpoint here
            Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does java.util.concurrent help in C#?

Comment: @Lasse : The question shouldn't be specific to C#. It can be the same doubt in case of java. Mine answer is related to java

Comment: I'm sorry, but if he needs his answer for a .NET program then he's entirely entitled to asking a question about .NET and C#. If you want the answer for a Java program, you need to ask it yourself. I rejected your proposed edit to add the java tags. This is a .NET question, the problem probably exists in java and lots of other runtimes/languages, but if you want a general answer, please ask your own question and don't try to make this one into something it is not.

Comment: And since he's asking for code, knowing the code for Java or Objective-C or whatever isn't going to help him at all. I also assume (but I could of course be wrong), that the technicalities involved in getting that information depends on the runtime, language, operating system, whatnot, so a general catch-all answer probably doesn't exist.

Comment: @Lasse : No problem. Now, I answered for C# also.How about that ?

Comment: @ All : Sorry for this answer. I didn't see Hans Passant already answered this question. Just provided the link of his answer which he already gave for another question.