# How to add diagnostics to C# lock function for multithreading debugging

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, mutex

Is it possible to shim the C# lock function, to add diagnostics?
I would love to see whenever a lock is taken or released, the lock count, and the managed thread id of the thread taking the lock.

In C++ you write your own Mutex class and provide your own lock function, and you can add in those kind of diags yourself.

Is it possible to wrap the lock function or shim the function to provide diagnostics?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: *lock* is not a function, it is a keyword in the C# language.  While you can replace it, you won't get the same semantics out of your replacement unless you code carefully.  Bad idea.  Just [use the debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5135181/17034) to find out whether the lock is taken and what thread owns the lock.

Comment: I'm currently bracketing the lock entry and exit points with log4net log statements to hunt for a thread that attempts to gain lock and never progresses.  But it's labourious.  Identifying the owner should be feasible with log4net as I get the managed thread id in the log entry.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't shim the `lock` statement but you certainly can implement your own lock class that delegates to the `Monitor` class (which underlies `lock`).

The C# spec 8.12 says that a `lock` statement is "precisely equivalent" to:

```
bool __lockWasTaken = false;
try {
    System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(x, ref __lockWasTaken);
    ...
}
finally {
    if (__lockWasTaken) System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(x);
}
```

So there is no way to "hook in". I wonder, though, what happens if you define your own method `System.Threading.Monitor.Enter`... You will never get the compiler to use it because it is an ambiguous name. But the spec does not say what happens then.

You can probably install a custom CLR host or profiler and use native APIs to shim locks. That's a nuclear option, though.

Comment: So could I write an alternative to lock (eg MyLock etc), that does what lock does, but yields more diags?  Specifically I am looking for a deadlock hang, where an attempt to gain the lock fails.  I would use the MyLock class for diags only, and swap back to lock() for prod code, but a debug lock class would be exactly the kind of thing I need.  I know there would be some hacking to replace each lock() call, but that is life.

Comment: If you write your own class you can do whatever you want. That works. You just can't use the `lock` statement, then. Using Roslyn, or maybe the R# pattern replace feature, you should be able to swap your own lock in and out at will (by modifying source code).

Comment: I have to admit I don't understand how to implement an alternative to lock() that would work in a similar way.  lock() wraps a group of statements - how would I pass the statement block into the class?  Apologies, I am out at the edge of my C# knowledge here.

Comment: Implement your debug lock with `IDisposable` and use it in a using with a using block: `using(new DebugLock(lockobject)) {...//Do stuff}`

Comment: After a bit of thorough googlage, I found this, which looks like a deadlock detecting wrapper around the Monitor class.  Hans (above) is correct that you should not try to re-write lock(), as lock is backed up in the JIT to make it bulletproof, but for diags, this could be useful... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163352.aspx

Comment: I am now using DdMonitor by Stephen Toub at MSDN, and it is extremely useful.  I have adapted it to report instances where a thread takes more than one lock, which helps me prune back potential exposure to deadlocks.  I would strongly recommend it, it should be part of the framework.