# stopped in the debugger with a C# thread hung on a lock statement, how do I figure out which thread currently owns the lock?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Suppose there's a multitude of places in a project which lock on a given object.  When experiencing a hung thread, we see the thread is hung sitting on a lock statement, attempting to acquire the lock on a specified object.

Is there a way to ask the debugger which thread currently owns the lock for a given object?  Am thinking that may help debugging this.

Am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 on Windows 10 64-bit to debug a C# managed application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3524126/17034

Comment: @HansPassant I found that when I originally searched.  It doesn't answer the need though.  I'm not inside the thread which acquired the lock I'm looking at a thread trying to acquire the lock and unable to do so and am not sure which place in the code (of many) acquired the lock.  My question is if the debugger can be used to tell me exactly which thread currently owns the lock.

Comment: That is not a requirement at all, no idea why you'd think it is.

Comment: @HansPassant I have a thread stuck attempting to acquire a lock on an object.  Some other code already acquired the lock.  I'd like to find out which thread successfully acquired the lock for the specified object.  In other words, who owns the lock right now?  Which thread owns the lock I'm trying to acquire?  Does that make sense?